# Zend Framework: select element - how to set required?

Tags: zend-framework, selection, validation

how to set status "required" for Zend_Form_Element_Select when it has value "0"?

```
$country = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('wbm_country');
    $country->setLabel('Select:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addMultiOptions(array(0 => ' ----------- ') + $this->_countries_Select);
```

When wbm_country is 0 it doesn't show error at all.:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want 0 to give an error you can use

```
    $required = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty ();
    $required->setType ($required->getType() | Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::INTEGER | Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::ZERO);

    $country = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('wbm_country');
    $country->setLabel('Select:')
    ->addValidators (array ($required))
    ->addMultiOptions(array(0 => ' ----------- ') + $this->_countries_Select);
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you shouldnt put 0 as key, but '' (as being an empty string). But I'm not sure!